# Find element by only a part of its XPath using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to find elements which have changing XPaths with only one part staying the same:

```
//*[@id="foo"]div[2]/div[1]/time
//*[@id="bar"]div/div[2]/div[1]/time
//*[@id="bat"]div[1]div[2]/div[1]/time
```

I already tried using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/div[2]/div[1]/time')]")` but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is some example HTML:

```
<div class="entry-container">
<div class="entry-head">
<h3> some text </h3>
<time class="timestamp" datetime="2020-01-23 08:04:32 UTC">
Today at 18:34
</time>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the text from the `time` element.

Comment: Could you add html? And you can find more info about xpath here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Try `[contains(text(), 'time')]` instead.

Comment: Contains(text()) will not work for an xPath.  That will only find an element with the text of "time".  If you can provide the HTML for the element in question that will be much easier to assist.

Comment: I added some HTML to my question.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression:

```
//div/div//time
```

will give you all `time` elements anywhere having two `div` elements as ancestor. This works for the example paths you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this x path locator:

```
.//div[@class]/time
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below code using `Xpath` and `CSS` with webdriver wait so element will be loaded in `DOM`

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Xpath -1**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//time[@class='timestamp'])[1]")))
```

OR

**Xpath -2**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//time)[1]")))
```

**By CSS**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "time.timestamp")))
```

Comment: This does not work for me since the element i'm looking for is not the first element of the `timestamp` class (and the position varies).

Comment: which part is stable or static?

Comment: The only really stable part is the `time` element (and the fact that it is surrounded by at least two `div`s.

Comment: @Ramona I mainly tried with 'time' tag but i used in combination with class. do you want full list of time elements? or specific list or single time element?

Comment: I tried this too in the beginning... I'm just looking for one element and the only "identifier" that I could find is the XPath.

Comment: @Ramona try updated solution with xpath. hope it will help

Comment: @Ramona  Now it will select first time element irrelative to its it position. I have added 2 xpath please try with that and let me know.

Comment: It works in some cases, but I've built a workaround now. Than you for your help!

Comment: Ok i have one more solution. If you need then tell me

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`() and following xpath options.

**XPath1** :

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h3[contains(.,'some text')]/following-sibling::time[1]"))).text)
```

**XPath2** :

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h3[contains(.,'some text')]/following::time[1]"))).text)
```

**XPath3** :

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='entry-head']//h3[contains(.,'some text')]/following-sibling::time[1]"))).text)
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know the text in `h3` but thanks anyway!

Comment: There should be some reference to find the element unique way and I believe you should target the h3 tag.